# How to prevent Files with same Name?

Tags: sharepoint-server, event-handlers, properties, file

I have a service that takes a file from a library and send it to an already specified folder.

This becomes a problem when I'm having files with same names on diferent folders.

Lets say that the event sends files to **folder X**, and I have **fileA** on **folder A** and **also** a **fileA** but this one on **folder B**.

What happens is that the folder X will recieve the first fileA, and then will replace the first one with the second!

I'm trying to do it as a **ItemAdding event** to change the file name on folder X so I can have the 2 files on this folder. Possibly **fileA and fileA_2**.

But how can I get the file that is being moved, if `properties.ListItem` returns **null**?

thanks!

**edit:**
here is the code I was trying to do:

```
public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
       {
           base.ItemAdding(properties);

           if (properties.ListItem != null && properties.ListItem["Name"] != null)
           {
               SPListItem currItem = properties.ListItem;
               string oldName = currItem["Name"].ToString();

               foreach (SPListItem item in properties.ListItem.ParentList.Items)
               {
                   if (item.Name.Equals(oldName))
                   {
                       currItem["Name"] += "_1";
                       properties.Web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                       EventFiringEnabled = false;
                       currItem.SystemUpdate();
                       properties.Web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                       EventFiringEnabled = true;
                       break;
                   }
               }
           }


       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get **URL** of the file being added with `properties.AfterUrl` in `ItemAdding` event.

**EDIT:**

Check whether the specified file exists and if the file already exists cancel the event. That's the best you can do in `ItemAdding` event AFAIK.

Comment: that helps a lot, but instead of canceling the event, is there a way to change the name of the file to be moved?

Comment: Can you edit your post and include code from event that is doing the copying?

Comment: I added the code.

Comment: I was referring to initial event that does the copying of the file, not the one where you tried to rename destination file name. You said in your post: "Lets say that the event sends files to folder X, and I have fileA on folder A and also a fileA but this one on folder B."

Comment: I'm pretty much just using `file.MoveTo(string,bool)` after changing some custom properties.

Comment: Ok, before calling file.MoveTo method write somewhere original file location so you can read it in ItemAdding event like this: oWebsiteSrc.GetFile("original file location"). After that execute file rename and MoveTo. You could store original file location in web.Properties PropertyBag collection for example. I'll try to provide you with the code sample.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18593/discussion-between-slaven-semper-and-smith).